# output is still giving in console

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I am learning java web page development. in this code i just wanted to add two number and trying to get result in next web page by `res.getwirter` but it giving me answer eclipse console.

**my .java class**

```
package com.telusko;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    public void service(HttpServletRequest  req , HttpServletResponse res ) throws IOException
    {
        int i= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int j= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

        int k = i+j;

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("Result is :" + k);

    }

}
```

**my index class**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="add">

    Enter First Number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter Second Number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>

     <input type=submit>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you are outputting it to your console with 'println'. Where are you printing this in your webpage?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder to know if you have created the appropriate type of project, also I would like to know where is the "add" action that is specified in your HTML form tag. Are you working using Servlets 2.5? If that is the case then you should be using web.xml deployment descriptor and take a look to the name being used in that file and make sure the servlet name "add" matches with the one you put in the form tag.

On the other hand if you are working with Servlets 3.0, then you will probably would like to use annotations. I implemented your code in my IDE, it works fine, the only thing I did on my servlet was to add the `@WebServlet` annotation and assign a Servlet name.

For a better example, the steps I followed were:

1. Open Eclipse and created a Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse
2. Add Target Runtime (Server): Tomcat 8.5
3. Specify version of Servlet 3.0
4. Copy/Paste your code and add the annotation, make few adjustments in HTML

Code looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/AddServlet")
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int i= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int j= Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

        int k = i+j;

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("Result is :" + k);
    }
}
```

The HTML file located in WebContent folder is named as "index.html" and has the same content as yours:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="AddServlet">
    Enter First Number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter Second Number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
     <input type="submit" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Index at the beginning looks like:

[image]

And we get the result:

[image]

Hope the explanation helps.